# Gradle Build Error After Creating Google Maps Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've added an empty google maps activity to my project in android studio but I'm receiving this error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.
```

My app level build.gradle file contains:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "XXXXXXXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}







apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project level build.gradle file contains:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

How can I resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: the error showas exactly that there is a another version of the play-services in your app that is conflicting with the new one, please make sure no other dependency in you app

Comment: remove any google play services jar from libs if you have used it

Comment: Could be related to the version of firebase-auth lib, you should try using the same version of libraries based on play-services.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I only just installed the Google Play services SDK in the SDK manager prior to creating the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the package`com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1` to `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0`.

You should try using the same version of libraries based on play-services to avoid conflicts

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'` use this `compile com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'`